# #if DEBUG and return statements - Unreachable code warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings

I am facing this little piece of code:

```
#if DEBUG
return thisVariable;
#endif
return thatVariable; //<-- warning CS0162 here
```

It works fine, except I am getting a warning on the second return statement that the code is unreachable. Despite the warning, the code is actually very reachable when running the program in release mode.

Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: In what solution configuration do you have Visual Studio at the moment?

Comment: That will go away when you put it in release

Comment: Add a #else before the 2° return and #endif after

Comment: We are always developing in debug mode and only switch to release for public builds. Putting the second return statement under an #else statement removed the warning and is the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are performing a build where the DEBUG symbol is defined, then the compiler is performing its static analysis of your code *assuming* that first return is in effect and not excluded. So your code would be seen as:

```
return thisVariable;
return thatVariable;
```

In that context it is clear the second `return` statement won't be reached in such a build. When you switch to a build configuration where DEBUG is not defined, then you should not see the warning.

Consider using `#else` ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87a56b46.aspx)) to avoid the second `return` statement when DEBUG is defined.

There's also this relevant tidbit from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx):

> Although the compiler does not have a separate preprocessor, the
>   directives described in this [C# Preprocessor Directives] section are
>   processed as if there were one.

In other words, the C# compiler's static analysis is not aware of the preprocessor directives; they have been processed at that point already and the static analysis only sees the code that *resulted* from the preprocessing phase.

Comment: Thank you! using #else for the second return statement and placing the #endif below it removed the warning.

Comment: @Richnau if I use `#if DEBUG return x; #else return y #endif` in this way in VS2019/C#8? at least, then the else return code is not compiled and syntax errors in that code are ignored, no intellisense etc... making this practically useless... not sure if C# changed or something in my project settings